Why does a sound file sent by iMessage change the file name?
I have a standalone iMessage app that sends a sound file to another recipient. The sounds are .wav files, that are assets inside the app, with names like surprise.wav.
When I send the file, the sender sees the file being sent as surprise.wav, but the receiver gets a more random sound file name, like ms-0aeTxG.m4a.
Why is that happening? Is there a way to force the sound file name to be retained?
(I tried changing the title of the file's ID3v1 and ID3v2 metadata, but that didn't change the result)

Why wav format? Are there any special needs for a lossless format? This can use 10x times more bandwidth and disk space. However, idk why there are downvotes

It is likely just part of the ingest process on whatever temporary storage is being used on Apple's servers. It would be interesting to know if this behaviour extends to other file formats .flac, .ogg, .mp3. If you need file data to be kept the same, it might be best to send a .zip. If you need the recipient to play the audio straight from iMessage, you might be best converting to .m4a first to skip the re-encoding stage.

A title in ID3 is in no way meant and interpreted as filename. Moreover I'm surprised you can stuff ID3 into a WAV.

Thanks to @pierpy for pointing me to the solution.
The .wav files I was using are lossless, but can be quite large; somehow (on Apple's servers?) the sound files were being converted to a lossy, but quite small .m4a format, which changed the prefix file name as a result.
I changed all my sound files to the MPEG-4 format, using either afconvert (see this post for some hints), or using Apple's "Digital Masters Droplets" for a drag and drop solution (which sometimes needed tweaking a little to work with my sounds).
afconvert -v -f m4af -d aac -b 192000 -s 2 oldfile.wav newfile.m4a

It all works as expected now.

The weird part is why Apple decided not to keep the filename. That can be misleading to the recipient part
